# return false with url_for in flask

Tags: javascript, flask

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vote</title>

        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                document.querySelector('button').onclick=()=>{
                    return false;
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>            
        <button onclick="{{ url_for('chat') }}">hi</button>      
    </body>
</html>
```

**This doesn't seem to work**

I also tried:

```
<button onclick="{{ url_for('chat') }} ; return false;">hi</button>
```

And:

```
<input type="button" id="submit" onclick="{{ url_for('chat') }} ; return false;" >
```

But this one is giving me an error in console.

How to stop page from loading when the button is clicked? Can url_for() be used in `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

All `url_for()` does is return a string of an endpoint in your flask routes.

For example, if you have a route:

```
@app.route('/some_route')
def some_route():
    # do something
    return render_template('template.html')
```

`{{url_for('some_route')}}` will return the string `'/some_route'`

The `onclick` html attribute, expects a javascript function and not a string of a route. You could do the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vote</title>

        <script>
            $(function(){
            var someFunction = function(){
                 // perform actions
                }

            })

        </script>


    </head>
    <body>

<button onclick="someFunction()">hi</button>      


    </body>
</html>
```